# elasticsearch mapping for loop structure

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to do some mapping on JSON data looks like below

```
    "0": {
    "ip": "147.135.210.114",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "frequency": "46",
    "updown": -0.25579565572885,
    "viewCount": "28"
},
"1": {
    "ip": "171.255.199.129",
    "danger": "94.42262",
    "countryName": "Viet Nam",
    "countryCode": "VN",
    "frequency": "40",
    "updown": -0.088216630501414,
    "viewCount": null
},
"2": {
    "ip": "52.163.62.13",
    "danger": "94.18168",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "frequency": "46",
    "updown": -0.016932485456378,
    "viewCount": "5"
},
"3": {
    "ip": "151.80.140.233",
    "danger": "93.77446",
    "countryName": "Unknown",
    "countryCode": "Unknown",
    "frequency": "46",
    "updown": -0.31354507272874,
    "viewCount": "10"
},
```

as you can see, there are many objects (I am not even sure it's called object).
the object has different name(0,1,2,3,4...) and same elements (ip, danger ...).

How can I map elements with different name at once? is it even possible?

thanks in advnace :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map elements with different names with same mapping, but it is unlikely to be useful (depends on your use case).

There are mainly two options:

- using `dynamic_templates` to describe data with repeated structure;
- reshaping your data and using `nested` data type

#### `dynamic_templates`

Pros:

- does the job
- no need to change the data

Cons:

- it is harder or impossible to query
- risk of mapping explosion

#### reshaping + `nested`

Pros:

- does the job
- no restriction on querying abilities

Cons:

- have to change the data format

Below come the details.

### Using dynamic mapping with `dynamic_templates`

In general, use of [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/dynamic-mapping.html) lets you add objects of arbitrary structure, whose types will be guessed on the fly according to [some predefined rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/dynamic-field-mapping.html).

Dynamic mapping gives you less control over your data structures, and may lead to a [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings).

If you are fine with dynamic mapping and you just want to tweak the way it is applied, you may use [`dynamic_templates`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/dynamic-templates.html).

You would have to create a mapping before inserting any data, that might look like this:

```
PUT dyno
{
  "mappings": {
    "dyno": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "dynoField": {
            "path_match": "myPath.*",
            "mapping": {
              "properties": {
                "ip": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "danger": {
                  "type": "float"
                },
                "countryName": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "countryCode": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "frequency": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "updown": {
                  "type": "float"
                },
                "viewCount": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "myPath": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the `dynamic_templates` section is applied to all keys of `myPath` object (0,1,2,3,4 and so on).

After indexing the first document, the mapping you get from ES will actually look like:

```
{
  "dyno": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "dyno": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          ...
        ],
        "properties": {
          "myPath": {
            "properties": {
              "0": {
                "properties": {
                  "countryCode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "countryName": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "danger": {
                    "type": "float"
                  },
                  "frequency": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "ip": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "updown": {
                    "type": "float"
                  },
                  "viewCount": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "1": {
                "properties": {
                  "countryCode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }, ...
              },
              "2": {
                "properties": {
                  "countryCode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }, ...
              },
              "3": {
                "properties": {
                  "countryCode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }, ...
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that for every different "name" of the object ES created a separate portion of the mapping.

Although this does exactly what you asked for, it might not be useful. If you have a use case where you would like to select all documents with certain `countryCode` you might build a query like this:

```
POST dyno/dyno/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "myPath.1.countryCode": "VN"
    }
  }
}
```

But this will only return matches with objects with "name" `1`. If the set of "names" is big and/or is not known in advance, it will be very complex to query them all.

### Reshaping your data and using `nested` type

To be able to search on any object's `countryCode` you may want to reshape your data in the following way:

```
{
  "myPath": [
    {
      "__name": "0",
      "ip": "147.135.210.114",
      "countryName": "United States",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "frequency": "46",
      "updown": -0.25579565572885,
      "viewCount": "28"
    },
    {
      "__name": "1",
      "ip": "171.255.199.129",
      "danger": "94.42262",
      "countryName": "Viet Nam",
      "countryCode": "VN",
      "frequency": "40",
      "updown": -0.088216630501414,
      "viewCount": null
    }, ...
  ]
}
```

The tricky part is that, in order to be able to search the items of `myPath` list separately, one must use [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects) datatype.

In this case your mapping can be `dynamic` or `strict`, whatever fits you most. The mapping in `dynamic` case might look as simple as this:

```
PUT dyno
{
  "mappings": {
    "dyno": {
      "properties": {
        "myPath": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to do a query like this:

```
POST dyno/dyno/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "myPath",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "myPath.countryCode.keyword": "VN"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in order to query a `nested` field you have to use [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-nested-query.html). A nice place to get started with `nested` data type is [this chapter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) of the guide.

#### Final note about the nested field

In fact, for a `nested` field ES indexes an implicit document for each item in the list, so indexing and searching this type of objects is slower than non-nested one.

You may consider splitting these objects with different "names" as separate ES documents.

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank a lot. I did change the data format at it works like a charm :-)

Comment: @DavidK Great! Please feel free to accept the answer if it solved the issue.